# EntityFramework t4 template generate interfaces for each entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

I am trying to change a t4 template to generate an interface file for each entity. I want these entities to implement the generated interfaces. All the properties including the complex properties should be exposed in the interface. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Interface Generator

https://entityinterfacegenerator.codeplex.com

This project contains customized T4 templates which can generate interfaces and attributes for the DbContext class and entity classes.

Note: If this answer is correct, please mark it as good answer. Otherwise, it could be wrongly marked as spam due to the use of the external link in most of my answers.

Thanks